# Outlook.com API from php

Tags: php, outlook, outlook.com

I'm trying to create contacts on my Outlook.com account using the Outlook.com API, however they have no examples from php. I'm assuming you have to use the REST API call from PHP?

Apparently, the format is:

```
GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/contact.de3413e6000000000000000000000000?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Writing contacts using REST example is shown here:

```
POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts

Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json

{
     "first_name": "Roberto",
    "last_name": "Tamburello"
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to how to put this into php format. Perhaps, you should use the cURL command?

Comment: they're sending back json, so capture the returned data and then parse it back into a PHP structure with [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode).

Answer (score 1):

Simplest is to use cUrl to call the API. This should help you get started.

GET:

```
<?php 
$access_token = "TOKEN";

$api_url = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/contact.de3413e6000000000000000000000000?access_token='.$access_token;

$curl = curl_init($api_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));

curl_close($curl);
```

POST:

```
<?php 
$access_token = "TOKEN";

$api_url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts";

$curl = curl_init($api_url);
$curl_data = array(
    'first_name' => "Roberto",
    'last_name' => "Tamburello" 
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($curl_response);
```

Comment: How do you pre-authorize the app? I want this to be a cron job that runs once a day. It appears that the Live APIs require the user to authorize the app each time in order to retrieve that access token. I basically want a pre-authorized access token that can allow me to run a request once a day without any user involvement. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could save the user auth information and run the authorization call before fetching the rest. As always saving sensitive information like that should be encrypted in the database.

Comment: how to get the token?